# Find global minimum of the following

Tags: calculus

The global minimum value of 
$$|\cot x – 1| + |\cot x – 2| + |\cot x – 31| + |\cot x – 32| + |\cot x – 24| + |\cot x – 5| + |\cot x – 6| 
 + |\cot x – 17| + |\cot x – 8| + |\cot x – 9| + |\cot x – 10| + |\cot x – 11| + |\cot x – 12| $$
Then find $x=\operatorname{arcsec}(\alpha/\beta )$ where it is occurring.

Comment: Done now what ?

Answer (score 3):

The minimum is achieved when $\cot x$ is the median of the constants, i.e. $10$.

If $\cot x=10$ then $\sec x=\dfrac{\sqrt{101}}{10}$, which is not a rational number.

Comment: why median but not mean?

Comment: can you kindly please explain me the whole thing I was unable to understand it.

Comment: @idea The mean would be for the sum of squares.

Comment: Why not try it both ways, @idea, and see what happens?

Comment: @D.Manek: do you know what the median is ?

Comment: The constants are $1,2,5,6,8,9,10,11,12,17,24,31,32$, so the median is 10.

Comment: @GerryMyerson: quite right, my bad. Fixing.

Comment: Why use median while doing it and not mean?

Comment: @D.Manek: because the minimum of a sum of absolute deviations is known to be achieved by the median. This is not a "random" decision.

Comment: Can you explain how , please?

Comment: @YvesDaoust Thanks, i agreed.

Comment: @D.Manek: the curve is decreasing then increasing, the slope changes by two units at every point. Plot it to understand.

Answer (score 0):

Imagine if all these numbers are plotted on a number line:
take a random point Y anywhere on the number line. What do the mods represent? Distances from the points given (1,2,31...).That means |y-32|+|y-1|=32 (iff y lies between 1 and 32, similarly start considering pairs of numbers one from the end and one from start. Which are: (32+1)+(31+2)+(24+5)+(17+6)+(12+8)+(11+9)+
Only one number is left, 10!! |y-10| can be given a minimum of zero. and hence cot x=10.

Comment: Your answer is hard to read and it adds nothing new to the already existing answer, posted almost four years ago.

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).